# Animated Image to UIImageView

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, uiimageview, uiviewanimation

I have to set an animated **Image** to `UIImageView`.
see the following example of **Image** which I want to set on my `UIImageView` which has extension ***.GIF*** and I converted it into ***.PNG*** formate.

[image]

I already tried too many way to do it. but not get expected one. I need this technique to create my own custom **Progressbar**.
I assign this image to my `UIImageView`. but this is not animating..
If any one have any idea then please share it with me.

Comment: one point, This image is already animation type...

Answer (score 5):

You can't use `.gif` images in iOS devices. GIF animations not supported.

Instead of that you can add each frame of that `.gif` as a `.png` or `.jpg` image and you can animate it by code.

```
NSArray *animateImagesArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:myUIImageOne, myUIImageTwo, myUIImageThree, nil];
yourImageView.animationImages      = animateImagesArray;
yourImageView.animationDuration    = 1.0f;
yourImageView.animationRepeatCount = 0; // Repeat forever
[yourImageView startAnimating];
```

Another option is, you can put a `UIWebView` and load your `gif` in it.

Comment: Yep, but I converted it as **.png** then we can use it. but not reaches to my expectation.

Comment: that is simple. but for this method I have to add lots of **Images** in my bundle. which will increase my app size. and still this will not such smooth like above screen shot. R you getting my actual problem - @Midhun MP

Comment: @Sarat_Patel: Yes, I'm getting your issue. Another approach is place a UIWebView and load the gif image in it.

Answer (score 1):

For use file with.gif extension you can use this third-part library [***FLAnimatedImage***](https://github.com/Flipboard/FLAnimatedImage). It is nice library with demo app.

You can also change some code to make work it as you want.
If you have array of image (.png or another extension) you can use APPLE UIImageView:

```
NSMutableArray* animation = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for(int i = 0; i<20; i++)
    {
        [animation addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"image_%i",i]]];
    }

    UIImageView *player = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x, y, width, height)];
    [player setAnimationImages:animation];
    [player setAnimationRepeatCount:0]; //0 means infinite loop
    player.animationDuration = 2.f;// time for one hole loop for animation
    [self.view addSubview:player];
    [player startAnimating];//start animation
    [player stopAnimating];//stop animation
```

Also you could use CAKeyframeAnimation. It could inform you when animation begin and end.

```
UIImageView *animatedImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] init]; 
CAKeyframeAnimation *animation = [CAKeyframeAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"contents"];
    animation.calculationMode = kCAAnimationDiscrete;
    animation.duration = 3.0f;
    animation.values = someArrayWithImages;
    animation.repeatCount = 1;
    animation.delegate = self;
    [animatedImageView.layer addAnimation:animation forKey:@"animation"];
```

And add delegate methods:

```
- (void)animationDidStart:(CAAnimation *)anim;
 - (void)animationDidStop:(CAAnimation *)theAnimation finished:(BOOL)flag;
```

Comment: Please note : If u use `CAKeyFrameAnimation`  the array should be of type `CGImage`

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to do animation then you need to take set of images of one particular that effect then run each images in for loop and give animation effect.
Also if you still wanted to do then you can use OpenGL or cocos2d framework to go forward.

But as per iOS Standard just keep your UI clean and flat images.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, you have a `gif` file and want to display it in an `UIImageView` as animated.

Here is a popular GitHub Library which allows this:
[uiimage-from-animated-gif](https://github.com/mayoff/uiimage-from-animated-gif)

With this `UIImage` category, you won't need to parse the gif files to several images. This library takes care of the single images inside of the gif file and the durations for each image to be displayed for you.

```
NSURL *url = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"test" withExtension:@"gif"];
self.myImageView.image = [UIImage animatedImageWithAnimatedGIFURL:url];
```